# Using CreateInstance in C++ calling a c# class

Tags: c#, c++

I have a simple c# class library for trying to use it in c++ as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ESC_TEST
{

[Guid("DCA71C5B-FC20-4A34-BF92-E59CBE4AB1BB")]
public interface ComClass1Interface
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void test();
}

[Guid("241EB2C8-578A-4D14-B059-CB00AFA9E1ED"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ComClass1Events
{
}

[Guid("2913E43B-A184-4353-8F10-F233B260699F"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ComClass1Events))]
public class ComClass1 : ComClass1Interface
{
    public void test()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AVIRAM !!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}


}
```

in the c++ code i'm using #import of the .tlb file and then i'm using this code in order to call the methods from the c# class

```
class __declspec(uuid("2913E43B-A184-4353-8F10-F233B260699F")) ComClass1;
static const CLSID CLSID_ESC = __uuidof(ComClass1);
ESC_TEST::ComClass1InterfacePtr pDotNetCOMPtr;
HRESULT hRes = CoInitialize(NULL);
hRes = pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(CLSID_ESC);
```

I know for sure that the CreateInstance fails and I can't understand why.

Do you have an answer?

Thank you!

Comment: what `hRes` do you get?

Comment: After HRESULT hRes = CoInitialize(NULL); line I get hRes = S_OK
After hRes = pDotNetCOMPtr.CreateInstance(CLSID_ESC); I don't get it

Comment: So what *do* you get as final `hRes`?